# "Diventare" o "divenire" per una professione?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Quale verbo si usa per esprimere che una persona comincia a esercitare una professione, "diventare" oppure "divenire"? Ad esempio, quale tra queste due frasi sarebbe la forma corretta?

> - All'età di 25 anni *è diventato* assistente del professor Cinci all'Università di Bologna.
> - All'età di 25 anni *è divenuto* assistente del professor Cinci all'Università di Bologna.

Comment: Ti rispondo in modo semplice, poiché non sono un esperto di lingua italiana (docente). Io userei senza dubbio "diventato", mentre "divenuto" (da divenire) mi suonerebbe piuttosto arcaico. Tieni conto che io vivo al nord, quindi può essere che nel sud Italia sia il viceversa.

Comment: Suona meglio (ed è la forma comunemente usata) "il professor X", se X è un cognome.

Comment: @karoshi: Grazie! Adesso modifico il testo della domanda.

Comment: @karoshi In Sicilia sarebbe sicuramente “il professore Cinci”.

Comment: @egreg vero, probabilmente anche in altre zone del sud, però credo che la versione tronca sia comunque la più standard.

Comment: @karoshi Sicuramente più diffusa, certo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Come suggerisce Treccani online, diventare è il verbo più comunemente usato:

[Diventare vs divenire](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/diventare_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/): (Treccani online). [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=diventare%2C%20divenire&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiventare%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdivenire%3B%2Cc0):

> - Benché divenire e diventare siano perfettamente sinonimi e intercambiabili in tutti i contesti, diventare è di gran lunga più frequente nella lingua parlata, mentre divenire è sentito come parola ricercata.

Il concetto di [divenire](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/divenire_%28Dizionario-di-filosofia%29/) (non diventare) è usato in filosofia:

> - Concetto filosofico opposto a quello dell’essere ( ➔), quando quest’ultimo sia concepito come eternamente immobile e sottratto a ogni mutazione.

Comment: Come curiosità, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FSU_EJjp3s per un altro esempio (poetico) in cui "divenire", usato come sostantivo, non è sostituibile con "diventare".

Answer (score 5):

La forma regolare del passato prossimo sarebbe "*è divenuto*", sebbene "*è diventato*" è accettato ed è anche molto più comune.

Però devo notare che l'esempio dato suggerisce che  parliamo forse di una rassegna biografica, in cui caso il modo corretto sarebbe invece il passato remoto *divenne*:

> All'età di 25 anni divenne assistente del professor Cinci all'Università di Bologna.

L'uso del passato remoto è oggigiorno piuttosto raro nel parlare quotidiano. Personalmente, credo che questo sia sfortunato. Secondo me, la lingua italiana è molto più bella quando si mantiene l'uso corretto e completo di tutte le coniugazioni.